# Pass information between classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and I'm running into a problem.

I need to pass some information from one viewcontroller to another.  I've tried a number of methods and either get build error or don't make enough sense.

Here is what I have so far.

**In the second view controllers h file:**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *OwnerID;
```

The data should go into this property.

**In the first view controllers m file:**

```
MoreByUserViewController *moreimg =[[MoreByUserViewController alloc] init];
moreimg.OwnerID = ImageOener;
```

I think this isn't correct but don't know what else to write.

**The clang error I get:**

```
duplicate symbol _m_PageCounter in:
/Users/ianspence/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pickr-dohtanjxfozprjbuwlphjbhvxttm/Build/Intermediates/Pickr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pickr.build/Objects-normal/i386/PKRViewController.o
/Users/ianspence/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pickr-dohtanjxfozprjbuwlphjbhvxttm/Build/Intermediates/Pickr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pickr.build/Objects-normal/i386/MoreByUserViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is something else, now you are getting error for _m_PageCounter. I think twice you put m_PageCounter or used same variable in two different headers..

### in .h file just declare @class MoreByUserViewController. and add header file of MoreByUserViewController in .m fie.

```
    @interface MoreByUserViewController : UIViewController
    {
        NSString *mOwnerID;
    }
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *OwnerID;
   -(id)initWithID:(NSString*)inId;
    @end

    @implementation MoreByUserViewController

    @synthesize OwnerID = mOwnerID; 

    -(id)initWithID:(NSString*)inId
   {
      if(self = [super init])   
      {
          self.OwnerID = inId;
      }
      return self;
   }

    @end
```

//Somewhere else in code

```
MoreByUserViewController *moreimg =[[MoreByUserViewController alloc] initWithID:@"AnyIdOnUrWish"];
```

Comment: I fixed the error, but I can't get the info to pass through.  In the first view I used the same code that you suggested `MoreByUserViewController *moreimg =[[MoreByUserViewController alloc] init];`
`moreimg.OwnerID = @"Anything";`  and no information is passed through on the second view controller when breakingpointing.  I have MoreByUserViewController.h imported in the first view controller, and in the .h file of the first controller I have `@class MoreByUserViewController;`

Comment: @ecnepsnai, now updated above answer. I think now you are checking for different instance. So now follow above code and print OwnerID. You can easily track error now.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a circular reference? check out your header files.

Comment: Circular references often occur when you include files in your `.h` files unnecessarily. Try to include headers in your implementation (`.m`) files exclusively when possible.

Answer (score 0):

`duplicate symbol _m_PageCounter` means you have a constant or variable or function named `m_PageCounter` defined in two places. Specifically, in PKRViewController.m and MoreByUserViewController.m.

Your options:

1. Delete one of them.
2. Rename one of them.
3. Declare one of them `static` so they won't be visible outside of that source file.